# How to change text size (cpi) of Epson LX-310 dot matrix printer?

Tags: printing, printer, dot-matrix-printer

I have Python written program on the server, that uses a shared printer. Basically, it provide print out file with txt formatted.

Is it possible to change printer output text size for TXT file printed on an Epson LX-310 dot matrix printer?

All I can do is change the font style which is easy to change as it has clear documentation about it. And almost all Epson dot matrix printer has this feature which is pretty much same step.

The default text size is 10 cpi, and I want to reduce it to 12 cpi. Is it possible to do it in "set printer configuration" instead of ESC code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you may be out of luck.

[Page 36 of the User Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/48453/Epson-Lx-300Plusii.html?page=36#manual) shows the default settings you can make on the printer. Changing character size is not one of them.